# How to show recents topics below the forum's title (Wordpress + bbPress plugin)?

Tags: bbpress

I'm not very familiar with the bbPress plugin.
I would like to list two or three recent topics below the title of the forum
(as well as the number of their replies):

[image]

This is **loop-bbp_forums.php**:

```
<?php

/**
 * Forums Loop
 *
 * @package bbPress
 * @subpackage Theme
 */

?>

<?php if ( bbp_has_forums() ) : ?>

    <table class="bbp-forums">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="bbp-forum-info"><?php _e( 'Forum', 'bbpress' ); ?></th>
                <th class="bbp-forum-topic-count"><?php _e( 'Topics', 'bbpress' ); ?></th>
                <th class="bbp-forum-topic-replies"><?php _e( 'Replies', 'bbpress' ); ?></th>
                <th class="bbp-forum-freshness"><?php _e( 'Freshness', 'bbpress' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr><td colspan="4">&nbsp;<?php // @todo - Moderation links ?></td></tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>

            <?php while ( bbp_forums() ) : bbp_the_forum(); ?>

                <tr id="bbp-forum-<?php bbp_forum_id(); ?>" <?php bbp_forum_class(); ?>>

                    <td class="bbp-forum-info">
                        <a class="bbp-forum-title" href="<?php bbp_forum_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php bbp_forum_title(); ?>"><?php bbp_forum_title(); ?></a>

                        <?php bbp_list_forums(); ?>

                        <div class="bbp-forum-description"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    </td>

                    <td class="bbp-forum-topic-count"><?php bbp_forum_topic_count(); ?></td>

                    <td class="bbp-forum-reply-count"><?php bbp_forum_reply_count(); ?></td>

                    <td class="bbp-forum-freshness">

                        <?php bbp_forum_freshness_link(); ?>

                        <p class="bbp-topic-meta">

                            <?php bbp_author_link( array( 'post_id' => bbp_get_forum_last_active_id(), 'size' => 14 ) ); ?>

                        </p>
                    </td>

                </tr><!-- bbp-forum-<?php bbp_forum_id(); ?> -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

    </table>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Last time I checked, the bbPress plugin was in pre-alpha stage, so it's unlikely that you'll get support for it. Also, any answer that you might get could be rendered obsolete very fast. In other words, don't live on the bleeding edge if you can't take it.

Comment: @scribu So I should'nt go live with my bbPress based website? (And wait until March?)

Comment: Everywhere in the bbPress forums it says: "don't use the plugin on production sites yet".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scribu is correct. The code to do this does exist within the plugin, but that code is subject to change as the bbPress plugin continues to be developed.

If you're comfortable snooping through code and finding the functions to make this happen, we're happy to fix any bugs you might find along the way. You may also have more luck asking your question at the bbPress.org support forums, as there are a few people there currently testing the bbPress plugin and keeping up with its daily developments.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be added on loop-topic.php

```
<ul class="bbp-topics">

<?php while ( bbp_topics() ) : bbp_the_topic(); ?>

<?php if ( bbp_get_topic_forum_id() == bbp_get_forum_id() ) : ?>

<?php bbp_get_template_part( 'loop', 'single-topic' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Why? Please add an explanation to code fragments.